# Not able to select option from drop down list in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a value from drop down list. I have checked all posts related to it but not able to find solution.

Here is my HTML code for drop down list:

```
<select class="select2 visible" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ClientId must be a number." id="ClientId" name="ClientId" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Client</option>
<option value="22">ABC</option>
<option value="7">ABC1</option>
<option value="18">ABC2</option>
<option value="27">ABC3</option>
<option value="26">ABC4</option>
<option value="31">ABC5</option>
<option value="12">ABC6</option>
<option value="19">ABC7</option>
<option value="72">DGX Client</option>
<option value="57">DS Sampler</option>
<option value="25">Group123</option>
</select>
```

the code which I written in Selenium Webdriver to fetch value:

```
@FindBy(id="ClientId")
WebElement clientDropDown;
waitTime = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
waitTime.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(clientDropDown));
Select client=new Select(clientDropDown);
client.selectByVisibleText("DGX Client");
```

Error: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (6fa8cbb25476bea9b789aff19a6edf)] -> id: ClientId] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

[image]

Comment: What are the symptoms? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (6fa8cbb25476bea9b789aff19a6edf)] -> id: ClientId] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Before adding WebDriverwait statement I was getting this error:org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating under an assumption here.

See how your `select` has is hidden by the `display: none` style:

```
<select ... style="display: none;">
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assume this is because it is actually represented on a UI differently and this `select` is under-the-hood manipulated by the javascript whenever the actual dropdown representation changes.

If this is the case, you can either inspect what the actual dropdown looks like and use a combination of `click()` commands to open the dropdown and select the desired option (note that you would not be able to use `Select` class in that case as it is designed to be used for `select` elements only).

Or, you can *make the `select` element visible and continue*:

```
String js = "arguments[0].style.display='block'"; 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, clientDropDown);

Select client = new Select(clientDropDown);
client.selectByVisibleText("DGX Client");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked like a charm.code running smoothly without any error. Thanks again:)

Comment: btw..I just used these 2 lines code:   String js = "arguments[0].style.display='block'"; 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, clientDropDown);